# Which Map implementation is most suitable for River Crossing puzzle?

Tags: java, dictionary, graph

This is a project for a Data Structures class I am taking, so instead of providing coded answers, I would prefer your input on whether I'm thinking about this correctly, or if I'm missing something. Many of you have heard of this puzzle, but in case you haven't, here it is:

> A farmer is on the south bank of a river with his possessions: a goat, a wolf, and a very large cabbage. The farmer wants to get to the north shore of the river with all his possessions. The river is too deep and wide to wade across. However, there is a small boat available. The boat is so small that the farmer can only take one of his possessions at a time. It is important to note two other conditions.
>
> 1. If the goat and the wolf are left alone on the same side of the rover, the wolf will eat the goat.
> 2. If the goat and the cabbage are left alone on the same side, the goat will eat the cabbage.

The project requires us to create a Graph data structure to help the farmer decide how he should move his possessions to the other side of the river.

My current idea is that I will have a `Vertex` class:

```
public class Vertex {
    private enum Element{ FARMER, SHEEP, WOLF, CABBAGE }
    private Element type;
    private List<Edge> neighbors;

    public Vertex(Element e){
        type = e;
    }
    public List getNeighbors(){
        return this.neighbors;
    }

    public void AddEdge(Vertex destination, int depth){
        neighbors.add(new Edge(destination, depth));
        destination.neighbors.add(new Edge(this, depth));
    }
    private static class Edge {
        public Vertex destination;
        public int depth;

        public Edge(Vertex destination, int depth){
            this.destination = destination;
            this.depth = depth;
        }
    }
}
```

I also want to create a `Graph` class that contains a `collection` (HashMap, TreeMap, or other type of data structure) of the vertex's & edges as a field. It would also contain a field of two objects of my `Bank` class to represent the south and north sides of the river.

As you can see in the `Vertex` class, I have created an enum named `Element` which contains `FARMER, SHEEP, WOLF, CABBAGE`. After reading through the JavaDoc concerning Map implementations, I'm leaning towards using an `EnumMap` as my Map type. Eventually I will need to Iterate through this data in both BreadFirst search and DepthFirst search, but I can't think of any reasons why one Map implementation would be better than another for this purpose.

I have only learned about EnumMap from reading the JavaDoc rather than in class, so I want to make sure that I'm not missing any critical information that would make this a bad idea...

**So my question is: Does it make sense to use `EnumMap` in this context, or would a different Map implementation make more sense?**

If you need anymore clarification or background information, please let me know.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're using the map for.  You could think of an `EnumMap` as an array that's indexed by `Element` instead of by an integer, e.g. `map[FARMER] == some value`, `map[SHEEP] == some other value`, etc., which is not legal Java but hopefully gives you an idea of what this would get you.  If this isn't what you want, then you don't want an `EnumMap`.

Comment: @ajb I want to use the map to basically check whether or not a move to one side of the river is valid based on the remaining contents of the other side breaks the puzzle rule. For example, I'd try to move the cabbage across the river but check the Vertices on the other side, then notice they are Wolf and Sheep, which breaks the rules.

Comment: Sorry, that's not specific enough.  I still can't tell why you want a map and what you'd use it for.  A map has pairs of (key, value), at most one for each key.  If you want an `EnumMap`, then the key would be the `Element`.  What would the value be corresponding to each key?

Comment: Actually, it's not clear to me at all that you have a clear idea of what you're using your graph for.  I think you need to be _very clear and specific_: what do the vertexes represent, what do the edges represent, and most importantly, _how is your program going to use the graph to solve the problem_?  I mean actually having a step-by-step algorithm that a computer would follow, not a vague idea.  If you don't have that, then you're jumping into the details of the code too quickly.  If you do have an algorithm, please share it as it will help us answer your question.

Comment: @ajb After thinking about it, I guess I don't need a Map to solve this. I'll follow Patrick's suggestion.

Edit: I was thinking about this in the wrong way. I was thinking about it as if I was going through the elements but I really need to be navigating through the possible states after each move as Patrick suggested. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For those who might come across this post, the algorithm I'm thinking of is basically to look at the initial (and then current after first iteration) state and exam the possible outcomes: Initial State = ((FCGW) ()). Possible States= ((CGW) (F)), ((GW) (FC)), **((WC) (FG))**, ((GC) (FW)). The next iteration would use **((WC) (FG))** as the current state and evaluate possible the new possible states. This continues until the desired state is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the bank state should go in the vertex, and the edge type should be one of four possibilities (the three available animals or by himself). A hashset would be useful for detecting cycles in the graph, but this requires a proper equals and hashCode method for your Vertex class obviously.

The Graph class need not maintain a collection of edges. It simply needs a reference to the initial Vertex, as well as any number of utility methods.

As for the EnumMap, each Vertex could use that to store the edges to the next Vertex.